# How do I turn off Narrator?

Tags: mac, keyboard, narrator

I sorta button-mashed my computer keyboard and now there's a voice telling me what I'm doing and giving me definitions of things the mouse goes near or touches. The sound button on the keyboard is taking me to where the keyboard is, and I also heard him mention keyboard focus.

Can someone tell me how to get rid of it? I tried <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> but it didn't work. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Why are you typing like that?  You can't possibly think that is acceptable.

Comment: Please buy a new keyboard.

Comment: Besides being completely unreadable without bwDraco's edit, the answer was one simple Google search away. We expect people to do some basic research on their question before posting, if you're wondering why it's getting downvoted.

Comment: well I'm sorry i suck with computers. but i did look it up and could not find anything.                                                                                                 what did you search because i search "how do i get ride of narrator"and tried the stuff i found but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be by killing it's process. It *could* only work temporarily, if you didn't enable narrator at boot.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>

Search for `narrator.exe` and terminate it.

Alternatively:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> `taskkill /f /im narrator.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Preferences > Universal Access and turn off VoiceOver.

I found this with a simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=turn%20off%20narrator%20voice%20mac%20os%20x)...

Comment: ThanK you so much. I thought it wasn't going to work like all the other  things I tried. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer solved your problem, feel free to mark it as the correct answer.